# How to call all array value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So i have this code

```
foreach ($npd as $v):
   $data1 = array(
                   'no'   => array($v->some_val)
                 );  
endforeach;
```

$v->some_val shoulb be (aaa,bbb,ccc). But it just call (ccc). If i make like this :

```
foreach ($npd as $v):
   $data1 = array(
                   'no'   => array($v->some_val)
                 );  
echo $v->some_val;
endforeach;
```

Then it will be (aaa,bbb,ccc)

Can anyone help me ? Why the result is different ?

**UPDATE**
look, i used this to fill PHPWord table template, so i have do this :

```
$data1 = array(
                    'no'   => array($no++),
                    'tgl' => array('aaaa','bbbb','cccc')
                );
```

What i ask is, how i fill 'tgl' with value from database ? So its like ('aaaa','bbbb','cccc')

Comment: can you show your $npd array?

Comment: You are overwriting your variable every iteration!

Comment: i updated it. Please read again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Suppose `$npd` is `array('aaaa','bbbb','cccc')`

Then this code:

```
foreach ($npd as $v):
   $data1['tgl'][] =  $v;

endforeach;
```

will make this result

```
$data1 => array(
    'no' => array(1), //or whatever 
    'tgl' => array('aaaa','bbbb','cccc')
)
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY IRON MAN ! Thx for saving my life :D

Answer (score 1):

for example if you have this array

```
$data = array("aaa"=>"aaa","bbb"=>"bbb","ccc"=>"ccc");
```

here in for loop you can achieive like this

```
 foreach($data as $v)
{
    echo $v.',';
}
```

output :

```
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Comment: You just completely changed the intention of the code! I don't think this is what OP wants